# Excel (Custom Format): Format numbers to be displayed with a + as a thousand mark

Tags: microsoft-excel

I don't know how to explain this in simple words, so I will give you some examples.

I have some numbers and I want a custom format to display them like this:

0     to be  000+000

12     to be  000+012

123    to be  000+123

1234   to be  001+234

12345  to be  012+345

123456 to be  123+456

Comment: What should 1234567 be formatted as?

Answer (score 2):

Format cells > Custom > Set Type to `000+000`.